# Expand metric $g_{ij}$ about flat space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, approximations

I expand metric $g_{ij}$ about flat space $\delta_{ij}$

$$g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+h_{ij}$$

where $|h_{ij}|\ll 1$.

I would like to find $R_{ij}$, to linear order, in terms of $h_{ij}$, but I dont know what terms are negligible. Which $\partial h \partial h$, $\partial h$, $hh, h \partial h $, $\partial \partial h$ are negligible?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall that since $h_{ij}$ is small, when it is continous and smooth enough then its derivatives will also be small, in which case you can ignore $\partial h \partial h$, $hh$ and  $h\partial h$ but should keep $\partial h$, $h$ and $\partial \partial h$ (notice they are all linear in $h$, as you said you are expanding to linear order).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the assumptions you make about $h_{ij}.$ If $h$ fluctuates strongly, then high derivatives will be relatively large (and vice versa), but if $h$ varies very slowly then only taking low orders into account is sufficient. To make this quantitative, you can write for example suppose that $h$ is the product of an complex exponential times some slowly varying function $Q$, i.e.

$$ h_{ij}(x) = e^{ikx} Q_{ij}(x)$$
in which case
$$ |\partial h_{ij}| \simeq |k| |h_{ij}|$$
etc.
The moral of the story is that you need to consider which assumptions are right for the problem at hand - there is no universally valid rule of thumb that tells you where to stop.